# How to use default and runtime name for same task?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I've below dag

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
import pendulum
from datetime import datetime

local_tz = pendulum.timezone('US/Pacific')

DAG_ID = "demo"
with DAG(
        dag_id=DAG_ID,
        default_args={
            "owner": "GFT Reporting Services",
            "depends_on_past": False,
            "email": ["mailing@mail.com"],
            "email_on_failure": False,
            "email_on_retry": False
        },
        default_view="graph",
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 4, tzinfo=local_tz),
        tags=['demo'],
        catchup=False

) as dag:

    def get_runtime_params(**kwargs):

        dag_run: DagRun = kwargs['dag_run']
        message = dag_run.conf['message']
        period = message['period']

        Variable.set('trigger_period', value=period, serialize_json=True)
        return "Its Demo"

    def get_doing(**kwargs):

        print("doing Airflow")

    start = DummyOperator(task_id='begin_execution')
    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end_execution')

    with TaskGroup(group_id='demo_compute') as demo_compute:
    
        task1 = PythonOperator(dag=dag,
                                                 task_id='get_params_to_update_config',
                                                 python_callable=get_runtime_params
                                                 )

        taskName = Variable.get("trigger_period", deserialize_json=True)
        with TaskGroup(group_id=taskName) as inside_demo_compute:

            get_doingTask = PythonOperator(dag=dag,
                                            task_id='get_doing',
                                         python_callable=get_doing
                                         )

        task1 >> get_doingTask

    start >> demo_compute >> end
```

As you can see, `taskName` default value is assigned from Variable `trigger_period`, and when dag is triggered and running, it takes value from `trigger_period` variable only, but its updated by the value from `conf`

Any option to not to use `taskName` default value from `Variable = trigger_period` and manage it in Dag itself ?

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: could you explain what mean `manage it in Dag itself `?

Comment: I mean to say, not to use like Variables, which needs to be set first for default value. Create anything which is part of Dag Instance, just need to avoid using Variables

Comment: Could you please explain what you are using `Variable` for? Why can't you just set a static value to `group_id`?

Comment: To use default value for taskName (inside_demo_compute task group)

Comment: Could you explain why do you need to change the unique `group_id` dynamically? Looks like you just need a setting / flag. Why are you changing the `unique id`?

Comment: because, group id's value also gets used further in processing...so I need to assign some default value to task name when dag is not running, which is coming from Variable

Comment: ok. but why you can't put full `DAG` config into `Variable` and use static `group_id`? The `group_id` will be static but the processing will be dynamic depending on the `Variable`

Comment: I think you have not read my question fully.... when dag is not running, need some default value so that It could load at least in AIrflow UI without error. And at runtime, the value we get from conf, which is being pushed externally to dag while trigger and get used as taskName and processing too

Comment: yes. I don't understand why you can't use static `group_id`. And that's why I ask for details. First off all, `Variable.get("trigger_period", deserialize_json=True)` will return a `dict` but not `str`. The second, you told that `group id's value also gets used further in processing`. ok. You can switch processing / mode just using `Variable`. Why do you need to change  `group_id`? You can have the same `ID`, but your functionality and config will be dynamic. You can also restart part of the graph(or trigger task) using `UI`

Comment: @Maria It doesn't work this way. What is the purpose to dynamically change task names at **runtime**? How would scheduler manage dependencies and queue? Task is an executable unit of work and if you need to depend on some runtime then do all the calculations inside the task, passing the data between tasks via XCom/external storage. Relying on dynamic identifiers will eventually break everything and make DAG flow completely unclear (you even wouldn't be able to tell if some task was executed on some day because its name is dynamic)